# The *****.objects.all() below are not recognized by python they don't show up in the suggestions when typing. I've tried them both on IDE and console

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)


obj = Question.objects.all()
obj2 = models.Model.objects.all()
```

Comment: What does "not recognised by python" mean? `obj` should include all of your `Question` objects, `obj2` won't work.

Comment: the class Question inherit (models.Model) so both them should have objects.all() and other method such filter, get, etc. but both of them doesn't show those suggestions

Comment: That's not true. A default manager is added when your `Question` class is prepared. If you just try to access the manager of `models.Model` you'll get `AttributeError: type object 'Model' has no attribute 'objects'`